# Software for making lighting notes on a script

Tags: text-editor, image-editor

I am the lighting operator for a small theatre production. Right now what I do is write lighting notes (when to switch what on/off and what intensity) on a printed copy of the script. When the director makes changes, I scratch out the previous notes and write the new ones. This leaves the pages looking ugly real quick and causes me to have to reprint often.

Is there a program out there that could help me with this? I imagine something that would allow me to make visual notes next to certain lines on the script and easily edit them.